How to Display Only Tasks on the Board in Azure DevOps?
Right now I can choose to view Epics, Features and User Stories, but I want to only see Tasks without seeing the User Story, on my Board. It is an option to filter on Tasks in the Backlog, but not on the Board. Is there a way to also filter on Tasks for my Board?
enter image description here
I have tried to make a completely new work item to my process, but I would prefer to use the default "Task" one. I have also tried to make a Query, but was not able to use this on the Board.

You cannot add default task on the boards dropdown list, please check the reply detail below, thanks.


I have tried to make a completely new work item to my process, but I would prefer to use the default "Task" one.

The list type(Epics, Features and User Stories) on board is controlled by board settings->Cards -> Backlogs. You can only add custom workitem but default task is not supported.

On organization settings -> Process page(inherited process) -> Backlog level page, you can create the custom work item on top level, and it will appear on board settings to choose.

